# Custom Array Adapter doesn't print data

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am facing a problem, i have a `listView` that i fill using a custom array adapter, the issue is that when i use the custom array adapter, the data stored in the `ArrayList` won't show but if i use a normal `ArrayAdapter` the data will be shown. I need to use a custom array adapter to style the `listview` since i can't style it in the normal `ArrayAdapter`

here is the code:-

```
CustomAdapter adapter;
  Context context;
  ArrayList<String> data;
  ListView listView;
 private static String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_production_comments);

    //defining list view
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);



    //defining data array list to store retrieved data from database
    data = new ArrayList<String>();


    adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    context = this;

    Toast.makeText(this,"Loading Please Wait..",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    new AsyncLoadProdComments().execute();
}



protected class AsyncLoadProdComments extends AsyncTask<Void, JSONObject,
        ArrayList<ProductionCommentsTable>> {

    ArrayList<ProductionCommentsTable> ProductionCommentsTable = null;

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<ProductionCommentsTable> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        RestAPI api = new RestAPI();
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = api.GetProductionComments();
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            ProductionCommentsTable = parser.parseProductionComments(jsonObj);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("AsyncLoadProdDetails", e.getMessage());
        }
        return ProductionCommentsTable;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ProductionCommentsTable> result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            //Log.d("Data1", String.valueOf(result));
            data.add("Date: " + result.get(i).getDate().substring(0, 10) + newline + newline +
                    "Item: " + result.get(i).getItem() + newline + newline +
                    result.get(i).getComments());

        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        Toast.makeText(context,"Loading Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private int id;
    private List <String>items ;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId , ArrayList<String> list )
    {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, list);
        mContext = context;
        id = textViewResourceId;
        items = list ;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View mView = v ;
        if(mView == null){
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            mView = vi.inflate(id, null);
        }

        if(position % 2 == 0){
            mView.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
        }else{
            mView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        }

        return mView;
    }

}
```

Comment: might be the case that textview has 0 height and 0 width while inflation due to no text set on it also send layout id rather than textview id in your custom adapter

Comment: pass your custom layout into your custom adapter. then inflate the view. then find views inside the inflated view. and set values corresponding to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your using of array adapter is wrong. It has own array to store data, so instead of adding your data to data array list you shoud add it to adapter. It has method `add (T object)`